# Teamcity pass browser parameter for Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity

Is there a way to pass a parameter from TeamCity to my Selenium Tests, currently I have to edit my java code every time I need a different browser or different URL.

I want to edit these values without edit the code directly, and see if I can send this parameters through the Parameters Tab on TeamCity

Java Class

```
   public static final String vBrowser = "IE10";
```

Something like this

[image]

Comment: I don't know Selenium, but can't your Java code simply read the value of `%browser%` rather than use a `final String` (constant)?

Comment: Thanks @sferencik, I've added the following in my java code System.getenv("browser"); and it works fine on TeamCity Server.... now I have the following question, probably it is a dump question but I'm not familiar with this, if I run my tests locally it will fail because System.getenv("browser");  doesn't exist on my local machine, how can I populate that value in order to work on TeamCity and locally.

Comment: Just set the environment variable. On Windows, this would be `SET BROWSER=Firefox` (run that before running your test suite). It would be much more elegant to modify your test suite to take command-line parameters (e.g. `--browser=Firefox`).